# What happens if we give a negative trigger pulse before a monostable multivibrator reaches it's stable state

Tags: operational-amplifier, basic, multivibrator, monostable

[Monostable Multivibrator using Op Amp](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-monostable.html), from this link,

[image]

> Obviously there is a certain amount of time that the capacitor takes to charge again from -Vcc*β to VD (0.7v) and therefore during this period a second negative pulse may not start a new timing period.

Wouldn't a negative pulse force the op-amp into negative saturation, since at any point the voltage would be less than VD(0.7), thus starting a new time period

Comment: Please include the schematic of the circuit in your question. External links might not work in a few months or years.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an opamp monostable, driven by two pulses.

[image]

What one can see is that, after the "calibrated" pulse (on Vo), the capacitor must recover some voltage between the pointed tags (335-189) us.

If the time between input pulses is changed, then the width of the "timing pulse" can change or is something "random".

[image]